# Disassociating process pipes from the calling shell

Tags: python, bash, shell, fabric, scientific-computing

I am trying to use `Fabric` to send commands which will run many physics simulations (executables) on many different computers which all share the same storage. I would like my script to

1. `ssh` into a machine
2. begin the simulation, for example by running `run('nohup nice -n 5 ./interp 1 2 7')` (the executable is called `interp` and `run` is a function from the `Fabric.api` library)
3. detach from the shell and run another simulation on another (or the same) computer.

However I cannot get Fabric to accomplish part 3. It hangs up on the first simulation and doesn't detach until the simulation stops, which defeats the whole point.
My problem, according to [the documentation](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.1.8/faq.html#why-can-t-i-run-programs-in-the-background-with-it-makes-fabric-hang)
is that

> Because Fabric executes a shell on the remote end for each invocation of run or sudo (see also), backgrounding a process via the shell will not work as expected. Backgrounded processes may still prevent the calling shell from exiting until they stop running, and this in turn prevents Fabric from continuing on with its own execution.
>
> The key to fixing this is to ensure that your process’ standard pipes are all disassociated from the calling shell

The documentation provides 3 suggestions, but it is not possible for me to "use a pre-existing daemonization technique," the computers I have access to do not have `screen`, `tmux`, or `dtach` installed (nor can I install them), and the second proposal of including `>& /dev/null < /dev/null` in my command has not worked either (as far as I can tell it changed nothing).

Is there another way I can disassociate the process pipes from the calling shell?

Comment: Could the second step be changed to run inside a screen? For example; `screen -dmS physicstest run('nohup nice -n 5 ./interp 1 2 7')` would start a screen (or virtual terminal) named "physicstest" and should run the following command inside it. This way, even though the physics simulation is still running, the command to start it finished with the creation of the screen. Ideally, that would mean the shell should be able to disconnect immediately, instead of waiting.

Comment: Hi, I noted in my post that I do not have access to `screen`.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. If that's the case, I'm not sure if what you're asking is feasible. I could be wrong, but in my experience ending a shell kills all child processes. Do you have access to `netcat`? If so, you could send messages from the main computer, as long as there's a script running on the remote computers to interpret them.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you linked to gives an example of `nohup` use which you haven't followed all that closely. Merging that example with what you've tried so far gives me something that I, since I don't have Fabric installed, cannot test, but might be interesting to try:

```
run('nohup nice -n 5 ./interp 1 2 7 < /dev/null &> /tmp/interp127.out &')
```

Redirect output to /dev/null rather than my contrived output file (/tmp/interp127.out) if you don't care what the `interp` command emits to its stdout/stderr.

Assuming the above works, I'm unsure how you would detect that a simulation has completed, but your question doesn't seem to concern itself with that detail.